# Можно ли поднять VPN на ip-адресах соцсетей?

Tags: ip, proxy, vpn

вопрос такой : Оператор Megafon Таджикистан дает безлимитный трафик для: Facebook, Instagram, Twitter, текст в Viber и WhatsApp. Возможно ли перенаправлять трафик через их сервера или еще как-то читерить, чтобы юзать безлимитный интернет? VPN на их IP/подсетях возможен?

Comment: Можно, если вы дадите взятку одному из админов соцсети

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, если такая возможность - "перенаправлять трафик через их сервера или еще как-то читерить" - будет, то Мегафон перестанет давать безлимитный трафик на них. По крайней мере, если такое "читерство" примет массовый характер

Вообще, есть такой проект - [ip over Facebook](https://github.com/beneri/ip-over-facebook). И такой проект не один -есть еще разные способы туннелирования трафика. Найти их довольно просто - поисковым запросом "IP over <название того, через что Вы хотите получить доступ>"

Практически про каждый из них пишут "While possible, it is quite slow".

Прежде чем заниматься этим - туннелированием трафика -проверьте себя: попробуйте каким нибудь способом сделать свой доступ в интернет медленнее раз в 100-200. Если Вашего терпения хватит (никаких картинок, видео, анимаций, только текст, js тоже может не быть, потому что все ajax - запросы отвалятся по таймауту) - то имеет смысл продолжать эксперименты.

Но вобще, по моему, этото способ стоит использовать только, если никакие другиие способы доступа недоступны.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, почему-то когда я подключаюсь к vpn то скорость интернета увеличивается в несколько раз  это потому что провайдер вырезать скорость чтобы хватило всем  хотя они сами этого не утверждают ☹️ раньше можно было просто подключится к любой vpn и пользоваться интернетом на здоровья, но со временем они начали блокировать !

Comment: "скорость интернета увеличивается в несколько раз" - дело в том, что нет четкого определения, что такое "скорость интернета". Это - некое упрощение. Грубо говоря, Вы видите, что страница сайта полностью загрузилась за столько то секунд. Вполне возможно, при использовании VPN НЕКОТОРЫЕ сайты могут загружаться быстрее. Но тот механизм туннелирования траффика, который предлагается, без всякого сомнения сильно замедлит скорость доступа, просто в силу своей природы.